# How to get a dynamic attribute value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="parent">      
@foreach($cat as $category)

    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a id={{$category->id}}>{{$category->category_name}}</a>
    </li>

@endforeach
```

This is my script And it always give me the same value that is 1

I want always change value that comes from database

```
$("#parent li a").click(function(){
    var id = $('#parent li a').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: var id = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: `.attr()` will get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements. and you can find it out on Jquery API   https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @Arslan Akram, please accept the best answer among all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your jQuery function like this:

```
$("#parent li a").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');  // use `this`

    alert(id);
});
```

Note
The code you have used `var id = $('#parent li a').attr('id');` will always consider the 1st `<a>` of the 1st `<li>` which was wrong.

`this` will refer to the element which was clicked. Hence you would get the correct value.

Answer (score 4):

*value that comes from database*

I would recommend you to use `data-*` custom attribute to persists arbitrary data which can be fetched using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) in the current element context *this*.

```js
$("#parent li a").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');    
});
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a data-id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category_name}}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `click` event you can use `$(this)` as the clicked element:

```
$('#parent li a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use within your click handler the `this` reference - which is in this case the clicked element, than you can access the proper `id` attribute you are looking for.

```
$("#parent li a").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```